# How to extract path variable from responseentity in Junit testing

Tags: spring-data, junit4

Searched but unfortunately I do not get similar questions. I've pasted my involved codes. It uses Spring DATA framework.

1. Entity EscalationPolicy with ID automatically generated
2. controller to hand POST request to create an new policy
3. update JUnit Test

What I'm trying to do in the test is that first create one new EscalationPolicy with the object set by initTest(). Then fetch and update it. However the ID is unknown and I suppose I need to extract it from the return URI. I don't know how to do it after Mockmvc perform and appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "T_ESCALATIONPOLICY")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class EscalationPolicy implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "policy_name")
        private String policy_name;
        ...
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class EscalationPolicyResource {
    ...
        /**
         * POST  /escalationPolicys -> Create a new escalationPolicy.
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/escalationPolicys",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @Timed
        public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody EscalationPolicy escalationPolicy) throws URISyntaxException {
            log.debug("REST request to save EscalationPolicy : {}", escalationPolicy);
            if (escalationPolicy.getId() != null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().header("Failure", "A new escalationPolicy cannot already have an ID").build();
            }       

            escalationPolicyRepository.saveAndFlush(escalationPolicy);
            return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/escalationPolicys/" + escalationPolicy.getId())).build();
        }
    ...
    }

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @IntegrationTest
    public class EscalationPolicyResourceTest {
        @Before
        public void initTest() {        
            escalationPolicy = new EscalationPolicy();
            escalationPolicy.setPolicy_name("Policy Test");
            ...
        }

        @Test
        @Transactional
        public void updatePolicy() throws Exception {
            // Create the EscalationPolicy
            restEscalationPolicyMockMvc.perform(post("/api/escalationPolicys")
                    .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(escalationPolicy)))
                    .andExpect(status().isCreated());


            // Get the created policy
            EscalationPolicy e = escalationPolicyRepository.findOne(id);
                                                                    ~~need ID here
        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it may not be the most elegant way to deal with it, I think a way to bypass the problem. I save the id in the header map and in the test code to extract it.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class EscalationPolicyResource {
    ...
        /**
         * POST  /escalationPolicys -> Create a new escalationPolicy.
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/escalationPolicys",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        @Timed
        public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody EscalationPolicy escalationPolicy) throws URISyntaxException {
            log.debug("REST request to save EscalationPolicy : {}", escalationPolicy);
            if (escalationPolicy.getId() != null) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest().header("Failure", "A new escalationPolicy cannot already have an ID").build();
            }       

            escalationPolicyRepository.saveAndFlush(escalationPolicy);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.set("policyID", escalationPolicy.getId());
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
    ...
    }

    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @IntegrationTest
    public class EscalationPolicyResourceTest {
        @Before
        public void initTest() {        
            escalationPolicy = new EscalationPolicy();
            escalationPolicy.setPolicy_name("Policy Test");
            ...
        }

        @Test
        @Transactional
        public void updatePolicy() throws Exception {
            // Create the EscalationPolicy
            ResultActions action = 
                    restEscalationPolicyMockMvc.perform(post("/api/escalationPolicys")
                    .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(escalationPolicy)));

            action.andExpect(status().isCreated());

            id = (String)action.andReturn().getResponse().getHeaderValue("policyID");

            // Get the created policy
            EscalationPolicy e = escalationPolicyRepository.findOne(id);
        }
        ...
    }
```